# generic method in java to sum up all the values in a given list whether it be String ,int,double

Tags: java

How can I write this method?

```
public static <T> void adds(List<T> k,int i)
{
    T y;
    List<T> g = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
        y+= k.get(i));}
    }    
}
```

What should I use for the sum?

I have tried declaring a type T as a variable to place the sum within it.

Comment: How do you plan to calculate the sum of strings?

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Please write it down properly.

Comment: say i have a generic list of type integer or double or String i want to add them all together and print the output of the sum so if the list type was integer i wish the sum of the integers to be printed the same with the double type and the string type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a generic method that takes a `BinaryOperator<T>` of the type to be *summed* and calls it to add in a reduce operation:

```
public static <T> T sum(List<T> list, BinaryOperator<T> adder) {
    return list.stream().reduce(adder).get();
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
List<String> s = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3");
sum(s, (s1, s2) -> String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(s1) + Double.parseDouble(s2))); //"6.0"
sum(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4), (a, b) -> a + b); //10
```

This allows the method to be free of type-specific "addition" logic (so String list can be concatenated, numbers added, etc.